# Boost regexp how to translate such PHP unescape function to C++?

Tags: php, regex, boost, boost-regex, html-escape-characters

Whe I had to [create CMS in PHP](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.3/co-cms/CMS/api.php)  I created simple `unescape html` function that looked like this:

```
function unescape($s) {
    $s= preg_replace('/%u(....)/', '&#x$1;', $s);
    $s= preg_replace('/%(..)/', '&#x$1;', $s);
return $s;
}
```

How to translate it into C++ using [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess it would look a bit like this:

```
std::string unescape(const std::string s)
{
  std::string temp = boost::regex_replace(s, "%u(....)", "&#x$1;", boost::match_default);
  temp = boost::regex_replace(temp, "%u(..)", "&#x$1;", boost::match_default);
  return temp;
}
```

But I assume the `.` (DOT) should only match hexadecimal values, in which case I'd go for something like this instead:

```
std::string unescape(const std::string s)
{
  return boost::regex_replace(s, "%u([0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[0-9a-fA-F]{4})", "&#x$1;",
                              boost::match_default);
}
```

*(note that I did not test this!)*